# Getting value of HTML Checkbox from onclick/onchange events

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onClickHandler()" onchange="onChangeHandler()" />
```

From within `onClickHandler` and/or `onChangeHandler`, how can I determine what is the new state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

**The short answer:**

Use the `click` event, which won't fire until after the value has been updated, and fires when you want it to:

```
<label><input type='checkbox' onclick='handleClick(this);'>Checkbox</label>

function handleClick(cb) {
  display("Clicked, new value = " + cb.checked);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/3/edit)

**The longer answer:**

The `change` event handler isn't called until the `checked` state has been updated ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/1/edit)), but because (as Tim Büthe points out in the comments) IE doesn't fire the `change` event until the checkbox loses focus, you don't get the notification proactively. Worse, with IE if you click a *label* for the checkbox (rather than the checkbox itself) to update it, you can get the impression that you're getting the old value (try it with IE here by clicking the label: [live example](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ijoqep/2/edit)). This is because if the checkbox has focus, clicking the label takes the focus away from it, firing the `change` event with the old value, and then the `click` happens setting the new value and setting focus back on the checkbox. Very confusing.

But you can avoid all of that unpleasantness if you use `click` instead.

I've used DOM0 handlers (`onxyz` attributes) because that's what you asked about, but for the record, I would generally recommend hooking up handlers in code (DOM2's `addEventListener`, or `attachEvent` in older versions of IE) rather than using `onxyz` attributes. That lets you attach multiple handlers to the same element and lets you avoid making all of your handlers global functions.

---

An earlier version of this answer used this code for `handleClick`:

```
function handleClick(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    display("Clicked, new value = " + cb.checked);
  }, 0);
}
```

The goal seemed to be to allow the click to complete before looking at the value. As far as I'm aware, there's no reason to do that, and I have no idea why I did. The value is changed before the `click` handler is called. In fact, the spec is [quite clear about that](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#checkbox-state-%28type=checkbox%29). The version without `setTimeout` works perfectly well in every browser I've tried (even IE6). I can only assume I was thinking about some *other* platform where the change isn't done until after the event. In any case, no reason to do that with HTML checkboxes.

Comment: Fortunately `onchange` works correctly in `+IE9`. [Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html)

Comment: Adding my 2 cents here: It seems that IE8 (and below, I assume), differentiates between a click down and a click release... and that the reason we're on this page is because it fires on click down instead of click release. Seems like checkboxes only activate on a click release - clicking down and then moving the mouse would register a click, but not modify a checkbox.

Comment: Looks like toggling the checkbox via keyboard navigation (`tab`+`space`) will also trigger the `onclick` handler (verified in Chrome 51, at least).

Comment: How to get the value of that checkbox on click of it??

Answer (score 43):

For React.js, you can do this with more readable code. Hope it helps.

```
handleCheckboxChange(e) {
  console.log('value of checkbox : ', e.target.checked);
}
render() {
  return <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this)} />
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386737/nextjs-javascript-referenceerror-array-is-not-defined-htmlinputelement-onchan I guess this is what I need but dont know how to do it properly.

Comment: @MarkWillowAldave sorry I don't use Next.js

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="onClickHandler()" id="box" />

<script>
function onClickHandler(){
    var chk=document.getElementById("box").value;

    //use this value

}
</script>
```

Comment: .value always gives 'on', use .checked which gives 'true' or 'false'.

Answer (score 2):

```
use onclick event on all checkboxes that you want to get their values whether they are checked or not.

<input type="checkbox" value="rightSideCheckbox" onclick='handleClick(this);'>

function handleClick(checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked){
        console.log(checkbox.value+"True")
    }
    else{
        console.log(checkbox.value+"False")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
 
const [checkboxval, setCheckboxVal] = React.useState(null);

const handleChangeCheckbox = (e) => {
   setCheckboxVal(e.target.checked);
}


render() {
   return <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleChangeCheckbox(e)}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).