# jQuery > on checkbox change run code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rows of "To Do" on a checklist, each row has a "Completed" checkbox.  Upon clicking the box with the mouse, the following code runs and correctly posts the information (updates the database to track that the task has been completed):

```
   $(function ()
 {
     $('[id*="howto_step_complete"]').mousedown(function ()
     {
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var howto_used_id = id.substr(id.length - 2);

         var howto_step_minutes = $('#howto_step_minutes' + howto_used_id).val();

         if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
         {
             var checked = true;
         }
         else
         {
             var checked = false;
         }
         var value = $('#howto_used_id').val();
         if (howto_step_minutes != '')
         {
             $.post("updateChecklist.php",
             {
                 howto_used_id: howto_used_id,
                 howto_step_complete: checked,
                 howto_step_minutes: howto_step_minutes
             },

             function (data)
             {
                 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                 var howto_used_id_returned = obj.howto_used_id;
                 var howto_step_complete = obj.howto_step_complete;
                 alert(howto_step_complete);
             });
             $(this).trigger("change");
         }
         else
         {
             alert('Minutes must be filled out before checking complete');
         }
     });

 });
```

The problem is, if a person uses tabs to move around the form and then uses the spacebar to check the box instead, this isn't triggered, as it's using mousedown.  I tried changing this to `change()` instead but then my alert box keeps coming up over and over again with "false".

It should be true since I've just checked the box and I don't understand why it continually comes up.

What can I use instead of `mousedown()` to get this code to post properly?

Comment: in change(), you can check if the checkbox is checked or not. If it is checked, let the code run. Try not using mousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to use the change() again and then removed the trigger, I think that was what was constantly popping the alert box and then changing it again, and looping.

```
$(function(){
        $('[id*="howto_step_complete"]').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var howto_used_id = id.substr(id.length - 2);

        var howto_step_minutes = $('#howto_step_minutes' + howto_used_id).val();

        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) { var checked = false; }else{ var checked = true; }
            var value = $('#howto_used_id').val();
            if(howto_step_minutes!=''){
             $.post("updateChecklist.php", { howto_used_id: howto_used_id, howto_step_complete: checked, howto_step_minutes: howto_step_minutes },
                        function(data) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                           var howto_used_id_returned = obj.howto_used_id;
                        var howto_step_complete = obj.howto_step_complete;
                        alert(howto_step_complete);
                   });
            }else{ alert('Minutes must be filled out before checking complete'); }
        });

});
```

I also had the true/false of var checked wrong/reversed.  Fixed that as well.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for another 14 hours.  I am selecting my own as it contains a complete solution.  Merely changing it to .change() as you mentioned didn't work as I had mentioned I already tried that and had the issue of the repeating alert boxes.  My answer contains the full solution with reversing the vars and removing the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try .change instead of .mousedown:

http://nelsonwells.net/2010/06/jquery-change-event-on-checkbox/

Comment: Use `.on('change')` so that it will always happen on the event. I have more success that way.

Comment: Why the downvote? See this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events