# Change listener not working on dynamically added content in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic, jquery-selectors

Trying to put together a dynamic form with little success.  Using a JSON doc as a source, I am populating a two-tiered form scheme.

First, a series of categories are added to make checkbox entries with ids matching the category.  Then the sub-categories are added to a second div with class names of their parent categories.

I'd like to listen to the checkbox event to toggle the view of the subcategories relevant to the parent categories.  I can use the dynamically generated selectors to .hide() the input checkbox element itself, but none of the listeners are working properly.  I get no alerts, nothing is triggered.  At a loss here, any help appreciated.

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
      <div data-role="" class="" id="page1">
        <button class="ui-btn" onclick="selectTemplate();">Std Template</button> <br>
        <form>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="checkbox" id="group1">
        </fieldset>        
        </form>
      </div>
      <div data-role="" class="" id="page2">
        <form>
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="checkbox" id="group2">
        </fieldset>        
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>

  </body>
```

JSON:

```
var tagTemplate = {
  family: {
    name: "family",
    description: "These are your family members.",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Joe"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary"
      },
      {
        name: "Marc"
      }
    ]
  },
  design: {
    name: "design",
    description: "Different types of design notes.",
    items: [
      {
        name: "inspiring"
      },
      {
        name: "fail"
      },
      {
        name: "wayfinding"
      },
      {
        name: "graphics"
      }
    ]
  },
  work: {
    name: "work",
    description: "Stuff for work.",
    items: [
      {
        name: "whiteboard"
      },
      {
        name: "meeting"
      },      
      {
        name: "TGIF"
      },
      {
        name: "event"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

JS:

```
function addTemplateItems (template) {
  $("#group1").empty();
  $("#group2").empty();
  // $("#group2").hide();


  for (var a in template) {
    console.log(template[a].name);
    $("#group1").append('<label><input id="' + template[a].name + '" type="checkbox" />' 
      + template[a].name + '</label>');
      for (var b in template[a].items) {
        console.log(template[a].items[b].name);
        $("#group2").append('<label class="' + template[a].name + '""><input id="' + template[a].items[b].name + '" type="checkbox" />' 
        + template[a].items[b].name + '</label>');

        console.log('"' + '.' + template[a].name + '"');
      // hide initial sub-tag collection
      // $('"' + '.' + template[a].name + '"').hide();

    // $().hide();
      }

    $('label.family').hide();
      var inputSelectors = [];
      var name = 'family';
      var inputSelector = document.getElementById(template[a].name);
  // add listeners to show+hide sub-tags
    $(inputSelector).change(function(){
        alert('something changed.');       
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
            $('#' + template[a].name).show();
        } else {
            alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
            $('#' + template[a].name).hide();
        }
    });

// $(inputSelector).hide();

  }

  $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
  // $("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup("refresh");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With checkboxes, you are encouraged to use "onclick" instead of "onchange". Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events).

Comment: Tried all manners of jQuery handler attachment, but the method outlined in this link was the only one I got to work.  thx

Answer (score 0):

use this with .delegate()

```
// add listeners to show+hide sub-tags
    $(inputSelector).delegate('change', function(){
        alert('something changed.');       
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
            $('#' + template[a].name).show();
        } else {
            alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
            $('#' + template[a].name).hide();
        }
    });
```

OR with .on()

```
// add listeners to show+hide sub-tags
        $(inputSelector).on('change', function(){
            alert('something changed.');       
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
                $('#' + template[a].name).show();
            } else {
                alert(template[a].name + ' checked');
                $('#' + template[a].name).hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: `delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
}` --> this is the same, delegate() is deprecated as well

Comment: .delegate() is preferred over .live() in the jquery version < 1.7 where as after jquery 1.7 they have introduced .on() over .delegate()

Comment: @mpsyp have you added the js code inside $(document).ready(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with `.live()` . This will attache the event handler to dynamically added elements as well. Here's the documentation for it: https://api.jquery.com/live/

Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: .live() is no more recommended by jquery. Instead make use of .bind() or .delegate()

Comment: @Abhidev, As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: what is the argument that .live() is not recommended anymore for? Thanks!