# Not able to create a table row from the check action of a dynamically created checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a row of a table on the check action of a checkbox which is created dynamically. The flow is not entering the function on the check event.

```
addCheckboxItems : function(form){
    var newBox = ('<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxItem" onCheck="JavaScript:addRowItems(this)"; id="checkBoxItemId" value="' + form.combobox.value +'"'+ '>'+form.combobox.value);
    document.getElementById("divCheckbox").innerHTML = newBox;

    }
    addRowItems : function(element){
    alert('Hi');
    if(document.getElementById("checkBoxItemId").checked){
        var tableRef =  document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
        var td1 = document.createElement("td")
        var strHtml1 = document.getElementById('checkBoxItemId').value;
        td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);

        var td2 = document.createElement("td")
        var strHtml2 = "NA";
        td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);

        var td3 = document.createElement("td")
        var strHtml3 = "<a>Remove</a>";
        td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g,count);

        newRow.appendChild(td1);
        newRow.appendChild(td2);
        newRow.appendChild(td3);

        tableRef.appendChild(newRow);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this.....Thanks in advance..

Comment: i really don't understand the first line of the question, pls edit or create a fiddle with your current code

Comment: Why the Java tag? I don't see any Java here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax gives an idea that you're creating functions in some object `addCheckboxItems : function(form)` but in your html event handlers `onCheck` search global scope for the function. So you should define functions like `addCheckboxItems = function(form)` in global scope.

Besides there is no `oncheck` event. There is `onclick` event.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/us0rjbx6/) with this corrections where you can get the idea (and debug) what I am talking about. It however crashes inside `addRowItems` because there is not enough context in your code the build a working app... But you got your handler running and can continue now

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your function can u try this

```
addCheckboxItems : function(form){
var newBox = ('<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxItem"
onchange="JavaScript:addRowItems(this)"; 
id="checkBoxItemId" value="' + form.combobox.value +'"'+
 '>'+form.combobox.value);
 document.getElementById("divCheckbox").innerHTML = newBox;

}
```

I added the `onchange` event of the `input` element. This should do the trick.

**EDIT**

Also you can try with the `onclick` event of the `checkbox`. It seems that the `change` event behaves differently in IE, so many users prefer the `click` event which is fired post change in the state of the `input` element. You can refer [Getting value of HTML Checkbox from onclick/onchange events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events)