# Checkbox passes nothing to Vue object on the first click

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a number of checkboxes looking like this

```
<input :disabled="update.spinner" v-model="searchRequest.age" :value="age" type="checkbox" :id="age" @click="getFilters(searchRequest)"></input>
```

and I have a Vue component

```
Vue.component('filters',{
        template:filtertemplate,
        props: ['filters', 'loadLimit','students', 'counter', 'hobbies','update','filterParams', 'filterLoaded'],
        data(){
            return{
                filteredData: this.filters,
                selectedHobbies:[],
                searchRequest:{
                    gender:[],
                    age: [],
                    hobby:[],
                }
            }
        },
        components: {
            'v-select': ('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
        },
        methods:{
            getFilters: function (obj) {
                debugger
                var self = this;
                //check if filterParams empty if true encode to uri
                if(!obj == 0){studentProfiles.getDatasAsUriParameters(obj)}
            },
            sendRequest: function(counter,url) {
                var self = this;
                studentProfiles.counter = 0;
                studentProfiles.students = [];
                studentProfiles.update.spinner = true;
                studentProfiles.getData(counter,url,this.filterParams);
            }
        }
    });
```

When i check a box first time, is appears to be checked on screen, but the **filterParams** are not updated. When i uncheck this box or check another one, the value of the first box is passed to **filterParams**.

What can prevent the checkbox from passing its value to params?

Comment: Did you try `@change` instead of `@click`?

Comment: @PankitKapadia, thank you so much. I tried it now and it helped. If you write it as an answer with a little more detail, I will accept it.

Comment: Sure. Have added the reference link where you can get detailed explanation about both the events. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@click` will trigger a click event and then it will ultimately trigger `@change` event. You are trying to check the value immediately after `@click` is triggered. `@change` is not yet triggered and so you are not getting the correct value.

Try replacing `@click` by `@change` and it should work as it will be triggered once the checkbox value is changed.

`click` and `change` event explained in detail by T.J.Crowder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471462/1292178)