# Function triggers when checkbox is checked, but clears when unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Here is a simple calculation that is run when a checkbox is checked:

```js
function calculate() {
   var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;
   var drinkRate = 2;
   var drinkCost = drinkRate * guests;

   //output
   document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = '$' + 
   parseFloat(drinkCost).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
Number of guests: 
<input type="number" name="guests" id="guests" value="4"><br>
Drinks<input type="checkbox" name="drinks" id="A" onchange="calculate()"><output id="drinkPrice"></output><br>
```

How can the calculation be cleared (or hidden) when the check box is unchecked?

Thanks

Comment: You can check the state of a checkbox through its `checked` property : `document.getElementById('A').checked`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `checked` property of checkbox to identify the checkbox is checked or unchecked. The demo with your Code as:

```js
function calculate() {

 if (document.getElementById("A").checked) {
  var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;
  var drinkRate = 2;
  var drinkCost = drinkRate * guests;

  //output
  document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = '$' +
   parseFloat(drinkCost).toFixed(2);
 } else {
  document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = "";
 }

};
```

```html
Number of guests: 
<input type="number" name="guests" id="guests" value="4">
<br>
Drinks: 
<input type="checkbox" name="drinks" id="A" onchange="calculate()">

<output id="drinkPrice"></output><br>
```

Comment: This answer make more sense because you should not be doing calculation at all if checkbox is unchecked. @Prashant - Good to format code before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you do not use the `onchange` event, use the `onclick` instead, for compatibility reasons best explained by @T.J. Crowder on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events)

Simply change the `onchange="calculate(this)"` inside the checkbox tag to:

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='calculate(this);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the checkbox check value is `true`.
Try this.

```js
function calculate() {
 if (!document.getElementById("A").checked) {
  document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = "";
 } else {
  var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;
  var drinkRate = 2;
  var drinkCost = drinkRate * guests;
  document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = '$' + parseFloat(drinkCost).toFixed(2);
 }

};
```

```html
 Number of guests: 
<input type="number" name="guests" id="guests" value="4"><br>
Drinks<input type="checkbox" name="drinks" id="A" onchange="calculate()"><output id="drinkPrice"></output><br>
```

Comment: You could greatly improve your answer by explaining your reasoning behind your solution, and how you actually did it. Also you could use a ternary operation to simplify the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the checkbox current state and reset the value if the state is false.

```js
function calculate() {
   var guests = document.getElementById("guests").value;
   var drinkRate = 2;
   var drinkCost = drinkRate * guests;

   //output
   document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = '$' + 
   parseFloat(drinkCost).toFixed(2);

   if(!document.getElementById('A').checked) {
        document.getElementById("drinkPrice").value = ""
   }
};
```

```html
Number of guests: 
<input type="number" name="guests" id="guests" value="4"><br>
Drinks<input type="checkbox" name="drinks" id="A" onchange="calculate()"><output id="drinkPrice"></output><br>
```