# Click vs Input vs Change for checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox, click, onchange

I have a form. I want to only allow form submit if the user checks precisely 4 out of 8 available checkboxes; and once the user checks 4 checkboxes I want to disable the remaining unchecked ones.

Should I add a hook to the `click` event? Or maybe the `input` event? Or perhaps the `change` event?

I'm overwhelemed by the amount of events that seem to duplicate each other's functionality.

I'm also confused by the documentation.

[MDN docs about `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event):

> For `<input>` elements with `type=checkbox` or `type=radio`, the `input` event should fire whenever a user toggles the control, per the [HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element:event-input-2). However, historically this has not always been the case. Check compatibility, or use the `change` event instead for elements of these types.

[MDN docs about `change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event):

> Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's `value`.

And below:

> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the `change` event fires at a different moment:

- When the element is `:checked` (by clicking or using the keyboard) for `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">`;

[MDN docs about `click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event):

> An element receives a `click` event when a pointing device button (such as a mouse's primary mouse button) is both pressed and released while the pointer is located inside the element.

Practice:

The below JS fiddle seems to hint that all 3 events are equivalent. Clicking the checkbox, clicking the label, focusing the checkbox and pressing space on keyboard seem to all fire all three events.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
for (const event of ['input', 'click', 'change']) {
  checkbox.addEventListener(event, () => {
    log.textContent = `${event}\n${log.textContent}`
  })
}
```

```html
<label>Toggle <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
</label>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

As per the docs `change` and `input` seem equivalent; `click` does not seem equivalent to the other 3 as per the docs but in practice it seems equivalent.

Do we really have 3 events that duplicate each other's functionality? Does it matter in any way which event I use?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 3 events duplicate each other's functionality because you are looking at a checkbox which happens to be a special case.

For example, if you were to take a text field

- The event `input` will fire whenever the text in an element is changed using the user interface.
- The event `change` will fire (on most browsers) whenever the text element loses focus. It would only be triggered once instead of after every keystroke.
- The event `click` will fire whenever a user clicks on the text field.

If we were to apply this to checkboxes (keeping in mind there is only one thing a checkbox can be changes into: either `checked => unchecked` or`unchecked => checked`)

- The event `input` will fire whenever the checked state is changed using user interface.
- The event `change` will fire whenever the checked state has changed 
  in an element [(or when the checkbox loses focus in IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events).
- The event `click` will fire after the check state has finished changing .

The 3 events have very similar functionality (almost duplicates) because they are all trying to do something different that functionally does the same thing on checkboxes. The only differences being subtle implementation details.

I would use `click` to avoid having issues from the user of diffrent browsers.

Answer (score 0):

They are not duplicated.  There are subtle differences.

`change` happens once the value or state changes, and the element loses focus.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
  console.log('changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="text">
```

`click` happens once the element is clicked.

`input` happens IMMEDIATELY once the value or state changes, before it loses focus.  This happens regardless of if the state changes as per a mouse or keyboard event.  A checkbox can change state by clicking it, or focusing on it and hitting the spacebar.  A `click` event would not catch the spacebar state change.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
  console.log('changed');
});

$('input').on('input', function(){
  console.log('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="text">
```

To test the lack of focus change and the spacebar change on the checkbox, you can click the input box and then shift+tab to focus the checkbox to hit spacebar.  It appears from the fiddle that for checkboxes, the change and input events both happen any time it changes, even without the focus being lost.

This differs from how the text field behaves.  So there appears to be some behavioral differences between the two elements in when the events are generated.  The checkboxes appear to follow a less strict implementation of the pattern, as opposed to input boxes.

Comment: `A click event would not catch the spacebar state change.` In practice it does seem to catch spacebar, as per my fiddle; I mentioned this in my OP.

Comment: Fixed the disabled comment.  Not sure why I thought I remembered that behaviour.

Comment: `To test the (...) spacebar change on the checkbox, you can click the input box and then shift+tab to focus the checkbox to hit spacebar.` I am sorry for repeatig myself but once again, if I add a `click` listener to your snippet, it would seem that `click` DOES catch the spacebar! I click the input and then shift+tab to focus the checkbox and then I press the spacebar AND the event is logged!

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of my answer.  The implementation of these events on checkboxes appears to differ from how they are implemented for other input elements, such as text boxes.

Comment: OK, thanks. I did read the last paragraph of Your answer however, to my understanding, the last paragraph was discussing `change` vs `input` and not `click`. Another paragraph of Your answer still says: ` A checkbox can change state by clicking it, or focusing on it and hitting the spacebar. A click event would not catch the spacebar state change.` I'm just explaining why I was (incorrectly perhaps?) understanding that You were asserting that `click` would not catch spacebar on a checkbox.

Comment: No click, for a checkbox, appears to catch spacebar.  `checkbox` just appears to be a unique case for event generations.  I would imagine radio buttons would behave about the same way too.