# Display a button when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem: I have the code in the sandbox and I want to display a button if the checkbox is checked and the maxAmount is greater than 1. The maxAmount condition is not a problem but the checkboxes. I don't know how I can get the "checked"-value of a specific checkbox. I think I can not do anything with index, because the index-values are used multiple times when mapping the optionModules.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Sandbox-Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-germain-e18wh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of checked checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox)

Comment: yes it helps to get the value of the specific checkbox. My problem is that I want to display a button behind each checkbox that is true. If I push the true/false-values in an array I don't know which value corresponds with a specific checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add a "onClick" to all of your checkboxes.
Like this:

```
<input onClick={(x) => console.log(x.target.checked)} type="checkbox" value={option}
```

And then you can push them into an array to filter whether your conditions are met.

Just like @Lars already mentioned look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471401/getting-value-of-html-checkbox-from-onclick-onchange-events).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I know which element in the array is the corresponding checkbox?

Comment: you can push an object into an array like.. onClick={(x) => someArray.push({ name: option.name, isChecked: x.target.checked)} if this helps?

Comment: Thanks, I need to check it. But the problem is that there are objects that have the same option.name in different checkbox-groups. The sandbox is just a snippet from a more complex function. But I'll check it!

Comment: You can add another field to the object, like "checkbox-group", then you can look for the group.name and the option.name :)